# Feature search in ArcGIS online using custom geocoder, works but the results are limited, how do i get more results?

Tags: arcgis-online, geocoding

So i have Geocoder hosted as a service on my Server, i then added it to AGOL via the utility services (Add Geocoder) now it allows me to do feature serach using the service and it works great expect it only returns 4 results. So i am stuck. How can i get it to return more then 4 results?

I tried add and chaning the maxlocation in the REST endpoint but that didnt seem to help anything.

Thoughts?